# What is the game they are actually playing?

Tags: plot-explanation, hall-pass

In Hall Pass (2011), Six guys playing some game with dollar notes.

[image]

What is the game they are actually playing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're playing [**Liar's Poker**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar's_poker), a sort of poker played with money bills instead of cards.

> Liar's poker is an American bar game that combines statistical reasoning with bluffing, and is played with the eight digits of the serial numbers on a U.S. dollar bill. The numbers are usually ranked with a zero counting as a ten, and a 1 being highest as "ace". Each player holds one bill, unseen by the other players. The objective is to guess how often a particular digit appears among all the bills held by all the players.

You can read more about the rules in the above link. It appeared in several other shows and movies. This is also mentioned in the [script](http://filmscriptsonline.com/posts/hall-pass/):

> CLOSE ON A BABY MONITOR - PULL BACK to reveal that it's in the middle of a POKER TABLE next to a pile of ONE-DOLLAR BILLS. Sitting around the table **PLAYING LIAR'S POKER** are Rick, Fred, GARY, HOG-HEAD, BAKER, and FLATS, all in their mid-30's to mid-40's.